# How to hold second process until finish the first process in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I got problem in hold the second process until finish first process. I am using an `AsyncTask`.

I fetch data from a MySql server. Sometimes it takes more time for fetching the data because I used a shared server.

Hence, sometimes the second process run before the first process.

Here is code.

Here is my `ListView` Code

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MainItemListNotes invoiceNotes = (MainItemListNotes) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);if (shareactivitycode.equals("Quote"))
        {
            if (invoiceNotes.getItemType().equals("Labels"))
            {
                getLabelQualityID(invoiceNotes.getItemID());

                getLabelPrice(labelQualityID);

                if (labelNoOfColour.equals("0"))
                {
                    double a = Double.parseDouble(lPurchasePrice);
                    double b = Double.parseDouble(lLowRate);
                    double c = Double.parseDouble(lSellRate);

                    double d = Double.parseDouble(labelWidth);
                    double e = Double.parseDouble(labelHeight);

                    Double f = ((d * e) / 625.0000) * a;
                    Double g = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.4f", f));
                    Log.e("0purchaseP", String.valueOf(g));
                    Log.e("0purchaseP", labelWidth + " * " + labelHeight + " / " + "625" + " * " + lPurchasePrice);

                    Double h = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.4f", ((d * e) / 625.0000) * b));
                    Log.e("0LowP", String.valueOf(h));
                    Log.e("0LowP", labelWidth + " * " + labelHeight + " / " + "625" + " * " + lLowRate);

                    Double i = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.4f", ((d * e) / 625.0000) * c));
                    Log.e("0SellP", String.valueOf(i));
                    Log.e("0SellP", labelWidth + " * " + labelHeight + " / " + "625" + " * " + lSellRate);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ItemList.this, NewQuotation.class);
                    intent.putExtra("itemid", invoiceNotes.getItemID());
                    intent.putExtra("itemname", invoiceNotes.getItemName());
                    intent.putExtra("hsncode", invoiceNotes.getHSNCode());
                    intent.putExtra("itemtype", invoiceNotes.getItemType());
                    intent.putExtra("labelwidth", labelWidth);
                    intent.putExtra("labelheight", labelHeight);
                    intent.putExtra("packing", labelPacking);
                    intent.putExtra("purchaserate", String.valueOf(g));
                    intent.putExtra("lowrate", String.valueOf(h));
                    intent.putExtra("sellrate", String.valueOf(i));
                    setResult(3, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is `getLabelQualityID(invoiceNotes.getItemID());` Code

```
private void getLabelQualityID(String itemid) {
    String URL = "myserverurl.com";
    class VoucherDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                    JSONObject product = obj.getJSONObject("voucher");

                    labelQualityID = product.getString("id");
                    labelWidth = product.getString("width");
                    labelHeight = product.getString("height");
                    labelNoOfColour = product.getString("noofcolor");
                    labelPacking = product.getString("labelpacking");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Voucher ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Sum Error ", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error : "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("itemid", itemid);

            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URL, params);
        }
    }

    VoucherDetails ul = new VoucherDetails();
    ul.execute();
}
```

Here is `getLabelPrice(labelQualityID);` Code

```
private void getLabelPrice(String qualityid) {
    String URL = "myserverurl.com";
    class VoucherDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                    JSONObject product = obj.getJSONObject("voucher");

                    lPurchasePrice = product.getString("purchaserate");
                    lLowRate = product.getString("lowrate");
                    lSellRate = product.getString("sellrate");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Voucher ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Sum Error ", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error : "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id", qualityid);

            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URL, params);
        }
    }

    VoucherDetails ul = new VoucherDetails();
    ul.execute();
}
```

`labelNoOfColour` comes from `getLabelQualityID()`
&  `lPurchasePrice`, `lLowRate`, `lSellRate`, `labelWidth`, `labelHeight` comes from the `getLabelPrice()` function.

Sometimes `getLabelQualityID()` & `getLabelPrice()` take time to fetch data. & `if (labelNoOfColour.equals("0"))`, the process execute before fetch data.

Sometimes `getLabelPrice()` process run before the completion of `getLabelQualityID()`.

Please guide me on how to hold the second process until the first process finishes.

Answer (score 1):

This is common that when you are running several `AsycTask`, one thread might get executed before the other. Hence to ensure the sequential processing, you need to put a listener to your `AsyncTask` to keep track of the thread has finished or not. I would like to suggest the following implementation.

Create an `interface` class like the following.

```
public interface ThreadFinishListener {
    void onThreadFinished();
}
```

Now create a listener variable and a constructor for your first thread which is `VoucherDetails` I suppose.

```
private void getLabelQualityID(String itemid) {

    String URL = "myserverurl.com";

    class VoucherDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        // Create a listener
        ThreadFinishListener listener;

        // Create a constructor
        public VoucherDetails(ThreadFinishListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                    JSONObject product = obj.getJSONObject("voucher");

                    labelQualityID = product.getString("id");
                    labelWidth = product.getString("width");
                    labelHeight = product.getString("height");
                    labelNoOfColour = product.getString("noofcolor");
                    labelPacking = product.getString("labelpacking");

                    // invoke the listener method here when you are done with your first thread
                    listener.onThreadFinished();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Voucher ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Sum Error ", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error : "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("itemid", itemid);

            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URL, params);
        }
    }

    VoucherDetails ul = new VoucherDetails(new ThreadFinishListener() {
        @Override
        public void onThreadFinished() {
            // Call the second thread here
        }
    });

    ul.execute();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: should i do any coding in ``` public interface ThreadFinishListener {
    void onThreadFinished();
}```? or is it work same as given you?

Comment: This is just an `interface`. Yes, it should work as it is in my code.

Comment: ok 1 more thing can i use this in listviewcode same as u describe in ```AsyncTask```?

Comment: I think the code should work. However, I did not test the code myself. Please modify if you get any error. I commented on the code where I made the changes. Please check the comments as well.

Comment: Ok, Thanks i will check & replay you.

Comment: Great! Best of luck!

Comment: Its not work. Process didnt go in second process. https://ibb.co/s19ChsX here is code.

Comment: I do not actually understand anything in your code. Why are you trying to put two listeners? Just call a function which initiates the second thread. Try to understand the code first, which should help in the long run.

Comment: In my code I have 3 process. I want to run it one by one. So, I put two listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You need a handler by which you can delay your second process until the first finishes. I am giving you a simple code example

```
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firstProcess();

    // Now adding a delay for second process
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           secondProcess();
       }
}, 5000); //It means delay of 5 seconds as there are 5000 milliseconds in 5 seconds

   } //end onClickView
    });
```

Comment: time is not fixed how much time first process take. So, its not work for me. & this code is for delay process not for holding process until finish first.

Comment: If 5 seconds not work for you, then try to increase the time e.g 10 seconds i-e 10000 milliseconds. Just use try and hit method and it will work. I used this method lot of times for my applications and it worked.

Comment: i already used this method. its every time takes 10 second. its not preferable for holing process.